# Why does SQL Server not support NVARCHAR(max) on full text search index?

Tags: sql-server

I am wondering;

1. Why does Microsoft SQL Server not support a full text index on a `NVARCHAR(MAX)` column?
2. Why is it limited to 900 bytes?

Any insights?

Comment: The full text search field could be `nvarchar(max)`, but any index in SQL Server is limited to 900 bytes. Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12717317/900-byte-index-size-limit-in-character-length#12717441)

Comment: Why? Because Microsoft decided to design the software that way.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thats why im wondering, and yes, microsoft design the software that way, i know that too, thanks for you helpful comment! XD