# Select by O(1) from SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, indexing, time-complexity

I looking for way to run select query by O(1).
Can I create index in this way that  SELECT by primary key will take O (1) time complexity?

Comment: Big-O on a sql select?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server Hash Indexes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318219/sql-server-hash-indexes)

Comment: @wilx That "duplicate" is based on a misunderstanding that the `CHECKSUM` function creates a hash index (it doesn't) and is from 2008. The next version of SQL Server (Or current version for early adopters such as this very site) *does* support hash indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [clustered primary key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177443%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) is organised as a [b-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-Based_Indexes).

The clustered key is not a [hash-based index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-Based_Indexes), which is required for [O(1)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_time#Constant_time).

I believe b-tree searches are [O(log n)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_time#Logarithmic_time).

So no, you can't

> create an index in this way that SELECT by primary key will take O (1)
>   time complexity?

Comment: It seems like there should be a way to search by id (primary key) in O(1) time. At least when all the table fields of fixed number of bytes. It would essentially be function the same as an array, simply calculating `address + offset` to directly `load` the row. No indexes (tree or hash-based) needed.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, some RDBMS engines have hash table indexes. That would AFAIK give you amortized 
constant time as you so desire. AFAICT, MS SQL Server does not have this feature.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2014 *does* allow [hash indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn133190%28v=sql.120%29.aspx).

For tables declared as memory optimized only.